# Dynamically modifying properties on a Golang struct{} value, given another

Tags: go

I have this code in a router handler

```
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var t person.Model
    err := decoder.Decode(&t).          // t is a struct value
    item, ok := v.People[params["id"]]. // ok is a struct value

    if t.Handle != "" {
        item.Handle = t.Handle
    }

    if t.Work != "" {
        item.Work = t.Work
    }

    if t.Image != "" {
        item.Image = t.Image
    }

    if t.Firstname != "" {
        item.Firstname = t.Firstname
    }

    if t.Lastname != "" {
        item.Lastname = t.Lastname
    }

    if t.Email != "" {
        item.Email = t.Email
    }
```

But I would like to make this dynamic, something like this:

```
["Handle", "Work", "Image", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Email"].forEach(v => {
    if t[v] != "" {
        item[v] = t[v]
    }
});
```

is this possible with Golang somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package for this:

```
func setFields(dst, src interface{}, names ...string) {
    d := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()
    s := reflect.ValueOf(src).Elem()
    for _, name := range names {
        df := d.FieldByName(name)
        sf := s.FieldByName(name)
        switch sf.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            if v := sf.String(); v != "" {
                df.SetString(v)
            }
            // handle other kinds
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with pointers to the values:

```
setFields(&item, &t, "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Handle")
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/eByr0NToRXZ)

If your actual goal is to overwrite only the fields present in the JSON, then do just that:

```
item, ok := v.People[params["id"]]. 
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&item)
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Op-7Ysjr8-r)

Comment: thanks this looks very useful, just curious, newb here, why use pointers to the values? Why not just pass the values? Is it b/c it will copy the object if you just pass the value?

Comment: a comment on what `reflect.ValueOf(x).Elem()` does would be nice - what is the `Elem()` call for?

Comment: also, doesn't dst need a type in the signature? `func setFields(dst, src interface{}, names ...string) {`, aka `func setFields(dst ?, src interface{}, names ...string) {`

Comment: [The Elem documentation says](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Elem):  Elem returns the value that the interface v contains or that the pointer v points to.

Comment: A pointer is required to change the value in the caller.  A pointer is not needed for `src`, but for symmetry with `dst` and the case where the struct is "large",  a pointer is used for `src` as well.

Comment: `dst` has type `interface{}` per the function signature.

Comment: yeah got it, so it shares the type with src. Ok next question - since booleans have false as the zero value, how do I know if the intention was to include the boolean key in the struct?

Comment: The question as posed does not distinguish a "default" zero value from a zero value that should be set.  This is true for string values as well as bool values.  I suggest asking a follow up question.

Comment: Any good way to do that? I guess the onus is on sending in objects that don't have zeroed-out values, aka, any value present is intentional.